# I am trying to make JS variables from my HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Why is this code not working? I cannot seem to transfer the HTML forms to the JS in the form of variables.
I am making a quadratic formula calculator (just for fun) BTW.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var a = document.getElementById(a1).value;
        var b = document.getElementById(b1).value;
        var c = document.getElementById(c1).value;
        var root = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c);

        var calc1 = (b2 + root) / (2 * a);
        var calc2 = (b2 - root) / (2 * a)
        function checkVal(){

        if(calc1 > calc2){
        alert("The lowest x - intercept is" + calc2 + "," + " the highest is" + calc1 + ".");
        }else{
        alert("The lowest x - intercept is" + calc1 + "," + " the highest is" + calc2 + ".");

    }; 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name ="inputvals" method = "get">
            <input type = "text" id = "a1" value = "">
            <input type = "text" id = "b1" value = "">
            <input type = "text" id = "c1" value = "">
            <input type=button onclick="checkVal()" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since `document.getElementById(a1).value` returns a string you need to do `parseInt(document.getElementById(a1).value)` .. or `parseFloat()`

Comment: You're getting the values before the user has had a chance to input any values.  You're even getting them before the inputs exist at all.

Comment: "Why is this code not working?" — Open the Developer Tools in your browser and **read the error messages**.

Comment: You need to put strings like `a1` in quotes. And you've never set the variable `b2`.

Comment: All the code should be inside the `checkVal()` function, so it runs after the user has entered the values.

Answer (score 0):

First, I moved the variables inside the `checkVal` function or else it will not pick up any entered values on click.

Second, you need to quote the id in `document.getElementById('a1').value`

Third, since `document.getElementById('a1').value` returns a string you need to do `parseInt(document.getElementById('a1').value)` .. or `parseFloat(...)`

Fourth, you use a variable, `b2`, which is not declared anywhere so I declared it, though does not know how it gets its value.

*When it comes to `Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c)`, I'm not a math guy so can't correct any mathematical wrongs in that part*

```js
function checkVal() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('a1').value) || 0;
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('b1').value) || 0;
  var c = parseInt(document.getElementById('c1').value) || 0;
  
  var root = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - 4 * a * c) || 0;

  var b2 = b;  // ???

  var calc1 = (b2 + root) / (2 * a);
  var calc2 = (b2 - root) / (2 * a);

  if (calc1 > calc2) {
    alert("The lowest x - intercept is" + calc2 + ", the highest is" + calc1 + ".");
  } else {
    alert("The lowest x - intercept is" + calc1 + ", the highest is" + calc2 + ".");
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="inputvals" method="get">
  <input type="text" id="a1" value="">
  <input type="text" id="b1" value="">
  <input type="text" id="c1" value="">
  <input type=button onclick="checkVal()" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

The variables are not "bound" to the fields. Changing the values does not change the value of the variable. You need to *re-read* them at the point when the button is clicked, to get the newly inputted values.

Your lines declaring your variables (`var a = document.getElementById(a1).value;` etc) along with the logic that uses them need to be *inside* your `checkVal` function.

Comment: There are at least two other problems with the code

Comment: Thank you for your input. How do you recommend I do this? Could you edit some of the code?

Comment: @meagar I followed your instructions, but when I run the code it does not seem to execute the function.

Comment: @MackayLJohnson: Other problems exist, but at the very least you should pretty much move all of your JavaScript code to inside the one function you have.  Since all of that code should happen in response to the user input.

Comment: @MackayLJohnson Then, as others have said, you need to open your developer console and start reading the error messages.